# How to implement universal link in ios 9.0 or above?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, applinks

Using Branch code for universal link implemented in Xcode but no luck lingering around since long plz help.

Comment: Shubham please post the code if you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details about your problem to help you, like error message, code snippet etc, is hard understanding the problem that you have with generic question.

By the way please check apple official content to understand how Universal links works and how to implement this

Reference material:

Seamless Linking to Your App

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/509/

Extend Your App’s Presence with Deep Linking

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/250/

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: Hello ferbass, actually i am using brach framework for implementing universal link in our project but still

Comment: please provide the error/code where you have problem

Comment: Hello ferbass, suppose i have shared my app story url in whatsapp and now when i click on shared link in whatsapp everytime its open safari browser rather than app is install in device.

Comment: did you implement `apple-app-site-association` on your server? please provide us more info of your implementation

Comment: Yes, i have uploaded on server side

Comment: can you have full procedure of universal link implementation from starting to end in ios?

Comment: @shubhambhadauria please checkout this tutorial https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272